# How to fix UIWebView deprecated Ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3, cordova-ios

After getting a message from apple regarding UIWebView

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage – Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

To fix it have updated Cordova 10 and cordova-ios 6.1.1. which fixed most of UIWebView references in the IOS platform but still it's showing few references in the core package (I guess)

[image]

Can anyone please help how I can fix remain UIWebView references?

I am using **cordova: 10.0.0 / ionic: 3.9.2 / cordova-ios: 6.1.1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIWebView` string matches in you screenshot refer to `vendor.js`. These do not matter as Apple only cares about the native (Objective-C/Swift) code of your app referring to UIWebView.

To search only source files of a relevant filetype, try this:

```
grep -inr --include \*.h --include \*.m --include \*.swift UIWebView platforms/ios
```

If this returns no results, your app's source code is free of UIWebView references.

However, if you still get the ITMS-90809 warning when you upload your binary to App Store Connect, it may be because the plugins in your Cordova app include/depend on 3rd party frameworks which reference UIWebView.
You can also check for this as [outlined here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-find-and-remove-uiwebview-uses-in-your-ios-app-d9395f7baacc) but the process it slightly trickier:

- Archive your app in Xcode
- Right-click on it in the Organizer window and Show in Finder
- Then right-click on the `.xcarchive` and Show Package Contents
- Open a Terminal window at this location and navigate to `Products/Applications/MyAppName.app`
- Then run the following command to scan the Frameworks included in your app for UIWebView references:

```
    for framework in Frameworks/*.framework; do
      fname=$(basename $framework .framework)
      nm $framework/$fname | grep UIWebView
    done
```

If there are any matches, you'll need to find which Cordova plugin incldues that Framework.
Then either update the plugin version to one which includes a new Framework version that doesn't use UIWebView
or if one doesn't exist, raise an issue against the plugin, fix it yourself and raise a PR
or if all else fails, remove that plugin from your Cordova app.

Comment: Thanks! I tried and found a few references in platforms/ios/Pods/Flurry-iOS-SDK. hope will get an update for that plugin soon.